# Not able to fetch the object from context correctly in django project

Tags: python, django

I am working on a basic ecommerce django website. I have a view for my category page which shows all the products and also I have functionality in my template that if the product is already in cart then perform the respective code.
This is the HtmL part that I am having problem in:

```
{% if product.id in list_cart %}
<div class="btn-group">
 <button class="btnabc btnabc-primary">{{list_cart.size}}</button>
  </div>
{% else %}
<div class="btn-group">
<select class="selection-2 border" name="size" required id="sizebox">
  {% for t in product.size.all %}
  <option value="{{t}}" id="{{t}}">{{t}}</option>
   {% endfor %}
 </select>
  </div>
  {% endif %}
```

This is my views.py:

```
def category(request):
    context = {
        'types' : Category.objects.all(),
        'prods': Product.objects.filter(),
        'cartItems':[],
        
    }
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        customer=request.user.customer
        order, created=Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)
        cartItems=order.get_cart_items,     
        items=order.orderitem_set.all()
        context['list_cart'] = order.orderitem_set.values_list('product__id', flat=True)    
    return render(request,"category.html",context)
```

When a person selects a size and adds it to cart till there it works fine but after that instead of showing the selectbox for sizes I want to show the size that was selected as tried in my code.The orderitem model has a size field:

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    product=models.ForeignKey(Product,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)
    order=models.ForeignKey(Order,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)
    quantity=models.IntegerField(default=0,null=True,blank=False)
    size=models.ForeignKey(Siz,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)
```

But it doesnt show the size instead shows an empty button.The {% if product.id in list_cart%} works correctly in showing the remove from cart button if item is in cart but it is not showing me the item size that was selected . Please help me with this.
Thanks

Comment: Well, given template and the view do not seem to match at all. Please try to elaborate what is supposed to happen here, sample data and desired output would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `{{list_cart.size}}` doesn't reference a size because `list_cart` isn't a single object. Therefore select the `list_cart` object you need the size too.

Try:

```
{{list_cart.0.size}}
```

(I have encountered a similar problem but found a different solution back then that wouldn't work here so I'm not sure this will be the full solution.)